# NA value not excluded in lm() in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataframe with Sex (Female=1, Men=0), Race (white=1, non-white=0), among other columns. There are some missing values in both Sex and Race (both are factor variables). Below is a screenshot of the Sex variable distribution.

[image]

However, when I ran the linear regression, no missing values are dropped.
Below is the regression output. As you can see, for some reason, both 0 and 1 show up for Sex and race. Does that mean R takes "NA" as the baseline? How can I fix the code so that lm() only takes in complete cases?

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that the NAs are not excluded?  I do not see anything about NAs in the output.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the code and results as text rather than as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that your "not available" data are coded as *empty strings* (`""`) rather than as `NA` values.  R removes only `NA` values automatically.  You could try

```r
mydata$Sex[mydata$Sex == ""] <- NA
```

or

```r
mydata$Sex <- factor(mydata$Sex, levels = c(0,1))
```

and try again ...

Answer (score 0):

you can remove all the rows with NAs with `complete.cases`:

```
all_nodes_group_merged.adj = all_nodes_group_merged[complete.cases(all_nodes_group_merged), ]
```

By the way I recommend to wrap factor vars as numeric:

```
lm(formula = Life_Satisfaction_6bp ~ as.numeric(Sex) + as.numeric(race_white) + item_count, data = all_nodes_group_merged.adj)
```

Factor vars in regression works in a special way, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159530/11180223

**Edit**

You can also convert it to numeric and try if it makes some sense:

```
all_nodes_group_merged.adj$Sex_num = as.numeric(levels(all_nodes_group_merged.adj$Sex))[all_nodes_group_merged.adj$Sex]
all_nodes_group_merged.adj$race_white_num = as.numeric(levels(all_nodes_group_merged.adj$race_white))[all_nodes_group_merged.adj$race_white]

lm(formula = Life_Satisfaction_6bp ~ Sex_num + race_white_num + item_count, data = all_nodes_group_merged.adj)
```