# Custom contrasts in R: contrast coefficient matrix or contrast matrix / coding scheme? And how to get there?

Tags: r, matrix, anova

Custom contrasts are very widely used in analyses, e.g.: "Do DV values at level 1 and level 3 of this three-level factor differ significantly?"

Intuitively, this contrast is expressed in terms of cell means as:

```
c(1,0,-1)
```

One or more of these contrasts, bound as columns, form a contrast coefficient matrix, e.g.

```
mat = matrix(ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, data = c(
    1,  0,
    0,  1,
   -1, -1)
)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]   -1   -1
```

However, when it comes to running these contrasts specified by the coefficient matrix, there is a lot of (apparently contradictory) information on the web and in books. My question is which information is correct?

#### Claim 1: contrasts(factor) takes a coefficient matrix

In some examples, the user is shown that the intuitive contrast coefficient matrix can be used directly via the [`contrasts()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/contrasts.html) or `C()` functions. So it's as simple as:

```
contrasts(myFactor) <- mat
```

#### Claim 2: Transform coefficients to create a coding scheme

Elsewhere (e.g. [UCLA stats](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm)) we are told the coefficient matrix (or basis matrix) must be transformed from a coefficient matrix into a contrast matrix before use. This involves taking the inverse of the transform of the coefficient matrix: `(mat')⁻¹`, or, in Rish:

```
contrasts(myFactor) = solve(t(mat))
```

This method requires padding the matrix with an initial column of means for the intercept. To avoid this, some sites recommend using a generalized inverse function which can cope with non-square matrices, i.e., `MASS::ginv()`

```
contrasts(myFactor) = ginv(t(mat))
```

#### Third option: premultiply by the transform, take the inverse, and post multiply by the transform

Elsewhere again (e.g. a note from [SPSS support](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/library/contrast.htm)), we learn the correct algebra is: `(mat'mat)-¹ mat'`

Implying to me that the correct way to create the contrasts matrix should be:

```
x = solve(t(mat)%*% mat)%*% t(mat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    1
[2,]    1    0   -1
[3,]    0    1   -1

contrasts(myFactor) = x
```

My question is, which is right? (If I am interpreting and describing each piece of advice accurately). How does one specify custom contrasts in R for `lm`, `lme` etc?

**Refs**

Comment: it should be matrix(ncol=2, ...) rather than matrix(col=2, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim 2 is correct** (see the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/36079/136579) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168858/136579)) and sometimes claim 1, too. This is because there are cases in which the generalized inverse of the (transposed) coefficient matrix is equal to the matrix itself.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth....

If you have a factor with 3 levels (levels A, B, and C) and you want to test the following orthogonal contrasts: A vs B, and the avg. of A and B vs C, your contrast codes would be:

```
Cont1<- c(1,-1, 0)
Cont2<- c(.5,.5, -1)
```

If you do as directed on the UCLA site (transform coefficients to make a coding scheme), as such:

```
Contrasts(Variable)<- solve(t(cbind(c(1,1,1), Cont1, Cont2)))[,2:3]
```

then your results are IDENTICAL to if you had created two dummy variables (e.g.:

```
Dummy1<- ifelse(Variable=="A", 1, ifelse(Variable=="B", -1, 0))
Dummy2<- ifelse(Variable=="A", .5, ifelse(Variable=="B", .5, -1))
```

and entered them both into the regression equation instead of your factor, which makes me inclined to think that this is the correct way.

PS I don't write the most elegant R code, but it gets the job done.  Sorry, I'm sure there are easier ways to recode variables, but you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something, but in each of your three examples, you specify the contrast matrix in the same way, i.e.

```
## Note it should plural of contrast
contrasts(myFactor) = x
```

The only thing that differs is the value of `x`.

Using the data from the UCLA website as an example

```
hsb2 = read.table('http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv', header=T, sep=",")

#creating the factor variable race.f
hsb2$race.f = factor(hsb2$race, labels=c("Hispanic", "Asian", "African-Am", "Caucasian"))
```

We can specify either the `treatment` version of the contrasts

```
contrasts(hsb2$race.f) = contr.treatment(4)
summary(lm(write ~ race.f, hsb2))
```

or the `sum` version

```
contrasts(hsb2$race.f) = contr.sum(4)
summary(lm(write ~ race.f, hsb2))
```

Alternatively, we can specify a bespoke contrast matrix.

See `?contr.sum` for other standard contrasts.

Comment: Thanks @csgillespie. Sorry if not clear: the question is how to specify custom contrast matrices (not how to get the built-in contrasts).

So in terms of your answer, the question is "there's contradictory advice about specifying a bespoke contrast matrix - which is right?"

Comment: But in each of your three examples, you get a bespoke matrix `m`, then use `contrasts(...) = m` to set.

Comment: the three examples give different results: 1 sticks the bespoke coefficient matrix into `contrasts(myFactor)<-m`, the next inserts  `solve(t(m))` and the final one inserts `x = solve(t(m)%*% m)%*% t(m)`. Are you saying solution 1 is correct, and one simply sets contrasts() to the coefficient matrix?

Comment: I see what you mean. I'll have to think about this a bit more. I'll delete my answer in the meantime, since you'll be more likely to get another answer